# Best way to write database layer(mysql) in restful webservice?

Tags: android, web-services

best way to write the database layer(mysql) in restful web service and service should return the database data in the form of json to client.

Answer (score 1):

Try restlet http://www.restlet.org for restful web service and ormlite http://ormlite.com/ for ORM database layer.